# how to save variable within a while loop

Tags: ruby

I have a variable `x` which is set to 10. And I want to write a while loop that increments that. I know you can easily just use a `for-loop` for this, but easy isn't fun. The code I have is:

```
def add(a)
   g = a + 1
   puts g
end

def loop(d)
   x = 0
   while x <= 4
       x += 1
       add(d)
   end
end

loop(9)
```

When ran I get 9, four times. How can I get this code to have an output of 9, 10, 11, 12?

Comment: There are so many problems with this code (besides `x` was never set to `10`, what contradicts the preface,) that there is no way to fix it save for completely rewrite from the scratch **after reading a book on ruby language**.

Comment: `x` is set to `0`, not `10` and your code outputs `10` four times, not `9`. Please fix either your code or your question.

Comment: What is your expected output ? `array` of numbers 9 to 12 ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you say `add(d)` and `d` is the parameter of your loop, `loop(d)`. Ruby does blindly what you tell him : `loop(9)`, so here d=9 and remains equal to 9. You need to increment the value of d. To do that `add` will now return the incremented value, and we assign the returned value to d (in `loop`).

To solve your problem you will want to do something like :

```
def add(a)
   g = a + 1
   puts g
   g
end

def loop(d)
   x = 0
   while x <= 4
       x += 1
       d = add(d)
   end
end

loop(9)
```

**BUT** and that's a huge but, your code is not the ruby way at all.

If I were to do it I would do it like this:

```
def loop(start_number, repeat_number, increment)
  repeat_number.times do
    start_number += increment
    p start_number
  end
end

loop(9, 4, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you rly wanna to use `while` and your expected outpit is `Array` numbers 9 up to 12.

Simply define the array variable before `while` loop and return it like this:

```
def loop(number)
  x, a = 0, []
  while x <= 3
    a << number + x
    x += 1
  end
  a
end

loop(9)
# => [9, 10, 11, 12]
```

**BETTER WAY**

But better way is use some ruby functions like `times` and `map`

in this case we use `times` and `map`

```
def loop(d)
  4.times.map{|i| d + i}
end

p loop(9)
# => [9, 10, 11, 12]
```

maybe this will helps.